# How to convert string timestamp values to datetime64 dtype

Tags: python, dataframe

The resulting DataFrame below lists the **Timestamp** values as the strings:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['00:00:00:19','02:11:00:07','02:00:40:23']})
```

What method to use to convert these string values to datetime64 so the sum() and mean() functions could be applied to the column?

Below is the screenshot of the DataFrame as it shown in Notebook:

Comment: Are those days, hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: Correct. The number represent the seconds and minutes and hours and days.

Comment: How can you have 40 hours in a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not the best way, but it's functional:

```
durations = (df.Time.str.split(':', expand=True).applymap(int) * [24*60*60, 60*60, 60, 1]).sum(axis=1).apply(pd.Timedelta, unit='s')
```

Gives you:

```
0   0 days 00:00:19
1   3 days 08:00:07
2   2 days 00:40:23
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

And `durations.sum()` will give you `Timedelta('5 days 08:40:49')`

Okay - slightly easier:

```
df.Time.str.replace('(\d+):(.*)', r'\1 days \2').apply(pd.Timedelta)
```

Comment: `days, hours, minutes, seconds = timestamp.split(':');inSeconds = int(float(seconds) + float(minutes) * 60 * 2 + float(hours) * 60 * 3 + float(days) * 60 * 4)`

Comment: Thanks!! I was hoping DataFrame would have a builtin method to perform the timestamps conversion!

Comment: It kind of does... but you need to supply either a string formatted like `5 days 11:03:12` or construct it via keywords arguments - it doesn't take positional arguments...

Comment: Terrific! Thanks again!

Comment: @user1107049 thrown in another example which formats the string into something `pd.Timedelta` likes that's more readable...